# Summation equivalence in proof of permutation as composition of transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, proof-verification

First of all, good morning everybody. My problem is related with a summation equivalence presented in one demostration. In the fifth summation presented in this link,  [here](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/mathematics-2/node133.html#app%3aprop%3acomp).
The one which replaces the sigma composed with tau with simply tau. I can't guess why that "less than or equal" is true. Because in case "l" and "m" are consecutive numbers, what you will get is indeed is that the "less-than symbol" should be a "greater-than" symbol.

Thanks you for the help.